# Typescript Function Interface overloading

Tags: typescript

I have the following code.

```
interface MySecondInterface<A>{
    type: A;
}

interface MyInterface {
    (val1:string, val2:string): MySecondInterface<string>;
    (): MySecondInterface<string>;
}

const myInterfaceFn: MyInterface = (value1: string, value2:string) => {
    return {
        type: value1 + value2
    };
}



const myInterfaceFn2: MyInterface = () => {
    return {
        type: "Text"
    };
}
```

You can find the code [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%0D%0Ainterface%20MySecondInterface%3CA%3E%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%3A%20A%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20MyInterface%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20(val1%3Astring%2C%20val2%3Astring)%3A%20MySecondInterface%3Cstring%3E%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20()%3A%20MySecondInterface%3Cstring%3E%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20myInterfaceFn%3A%20MyInterface%20%3D%20(value1%3A%20string%2C%20value2%3Astring)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20type%3A%20value1%20%2B%20value2%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20myInterfaceFn3%3A%20MyInterface%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20type%3A%20%22Text%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D).
I am getting error

```
Type '(value: string) => { type: string; }' is not assignable to type 'MyInterface'.
```

How will I create the interface to support both method signatures?

Basically, an interface for a function that takes either 2 arguments or no arguments. How can I do that?

Comment: Is making the `val` optional an option for you?

Comment: If you are trying to create a function that will accept both no parameters and a string parameter, you can define a single function with an optional val parameter.

Comment: I am trying to create a single interface which can be passed as a method argument, such a way that the argument can be invoked with three parameters or no parameter at all, in the example I used only one. I am updating example.

Answer (score 6):

What about using `type` instead of `interface`?

```
interface MySecondInterface<A>{
  type: A;
}

type MyInterface = ((val1: string, val2: string) => MySecondInterface<string>) | (() => MySecondInterface<string>);

const myInterfaceFn: MyInterface = (value1: string, value2:string) => {
  return {
    type: value1 + value2
  };
}

const myInterfaceFn2: MyInterface = () => {
  return {
    type: "Text"
  };
}
```

Comment: I've changed type MyInterface to be: type MyInterface = ((val1: string, val2: string) => MySecondInterface<string>) | (() => MySecondInterface<number>); // second part is now  (() => MySecondInterface<number>)  (<number> not <string>)  - all the other lines remain unchanged - but TypeScript does not complain (I would expect it to complain though). I'm wondering why ? Thanks !

Comment: it seems that: type MyInterface = ((val1: string, val2: string) => MySecondInterface<string>); is enough. The second part seems to be redundant for TypeScript.

Answer (score 4):

Your `myInterfaceFn` has to satisfy both function definitions in `MyInterface`.

The following code works fine!

```
interface MySecondInterface<A>{
    type: A;
}

interface MyInterface {
    (val1:string, val2:string): MySecondInterface<string>;
    (): MySecondInterface<string>;
}

const myInterfaceFn: MyInterface = (value1: string = undefined, value2:string = undefined) => {
    return {
        type: value1 !== undefined && value2 !== undefined
            ? value1 + value2
            : "Text"
    };
}



const myInterfaceFn3: MyInterface = () => {
    return {
        type: "Text"
    };
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Focus in on your error

> `Type '(value: string) => { type: string; }' is not assignable to type 'MyInterface'.`

`MyInterface` instances must be allowed to take `0` arguments. So the following errors:

```
const myInterfaceFn: MyInterface = (value1: string, value2:string) => {
    return {
        type: value1 + value2
    };
}
```

But if you mark both as optional (e.g. using default parameters) the error goes away:

```
const myInterfaceFn: MyInterface = (value1 = '', value2 = '') => {
    return {
        type: value1 + value2
    };
}
```

Comment: Ah ... So to clarify, if you define an interface of function types (i.e., more than one), then any function assigned to a variable typed to that interface must satisfy >all< types? I can fix OP's error by changing the type to `(val1?:string, val2?:string): MySecondInterface<string>;` so I think that's correct.

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure why TypeScript is ok with your interface declaration, because the two signatures have nothing in common. Maybe this is due to the fact how TypeScript handles function signatures (see sidenote below).

In your case, I would suggest

- make the `value` optional or
- create *one*  function and use overloading, e.g.

---

```
interface Result {
    type: string;
}

function myFn();
function myFn(val?: string):Result {
    if (!val) { return { type: 'foo' }; }
    return { type: val };
}
```

---

*Sidenote:* TypeScript is a little bit weird when it comes to call signatures. I guess this is due to the fact that it wants to be a superset of JavaScript. The following snippets illustrates this:

```
interface Fn {
    (a: string): string;
}

const f1: Fn = () => 'hi';
const f2: Fn = (a: string) => a;

f1();       // Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.
f1('a');    // OK, even though `f1` has no explicit argument...
f2('asd');  // OK
```